# Rails 6 grab results from Sidekiq Job - is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I've got Sidekiq job (`SyncProductsWorker`) which fires a class `Imports::SynchronizeProducts` responsible for a few external API calls.

```
module Imports
  class SyncProductsWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options queue: 'imports_sync'

    def perform(list)
      ::Imports::SynchronizeProducts.new(list).call
    end
  end
end
```

The `Imports::SynchronizeProducts` class gives an array of monads results with some comments e.g.

`=> [Failure("999999 Product code is not valid"), Failure(" 8888889 Product code is not valid")]`

I would like to catch these results to display them on FE. Is it possible to do so? If I do something like:

```
def perform(list)
  response = ::Imports::SynchronizeProducts.new(list).call
  response
end
```

And then inside of the controller:

```
def create
  response = ::Imports::SyncProductsWorker.perform_async(params[:product_codes])

  render json: { result: response, head: :ok }
end
```

I'll have some number as a result

```
=> "df3615e8efc56f8a062ba1c2"
```

Comment: If you need to display something to the FE, why are you using sidekiq to perform it async? The create action would be blocking anyway so why not just perform the job synchronously and capture the output that way?

Comment: Because I can't wait 3 minutes for everything to be done, unfortunately that's the nature of my external API. BTW This is a Rails::API only with Vue as a FE so I'm pretty sure I could whatever I want without blocking anything.

Comment: Use action cable to broadcast the result to your frontend when the job end

Comment: IDK, see my answer below. That is how we handle a React FE with a Rails API using Resque (same basic premise as Sidekiq) with long running tasks where the results are important to (eventually) display. Or use actioncable or something similar if you don't need to store the results.

Comment: Action cable, hmmm... any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe what you want is possible.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3532

> The return value will be GC'd like any other unused data in a Ruby process. Jobs do not have a "result" in Sidekiq and Sidekiq does nothing with the value.

You would need some sort of model instead that keeps track of your background tasks. This is off the cuff but should give you an idea.

EG

```
# @attr result [Array]
# @attr status [String] Values of 'Pending', 'Error', 'Complete', etc..
class BackgroundTask < ActiveRecord
  attr_accessor :product_codes
  after_create :enqueue
  
  def enqueue
    ::Imports::SyncProductsWorker.perform_async(product_codes, self.id)
  end
end

def perform(list, id)
  response = ::Imports::SynchronizeProducts.new(list).call
  if (response.has_errors?)
    BackgroundTask.find(id).update(status: 'Error', result: response)
  else
    BackgroundTask.find(id).update(status: 'Complete', result: response)
  end
end
```

Then just use the BackgroundTask model for your frontend display.